# If a ferromagnetic material is magnetized and demagnetized enough times, will it become paramagnetic?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-induction, magnetic-moment

I know that heating a ferromagnetic material above its Curie temperature will make the material lose its ferromagnetic properties. If a ferromagnetic material is repeatedly magnetized and demagnetized while staying below its Curie temperature, will its ability to be magnetized change?

For example, imagine a ferromagnetic steel pan on an induction stove. With continuous use, will the pan's hysteresis curve shrink over time, thereby making it heat more slowly, or will the hysteresis curve for the material stay the same?

Comment: If the phase remains the same, no.

Comment: Thanks Jon. Could you elaborate? Are you referring to the phase of the alternating magnetic field?